# Android Code Inspection: Implement custom inspection

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Android Studio helps the user writing good code in several ways. One of them is the Code Inspection which tells the user about some missing stuff or unused code. For example, when I have an Activity with a Fragment in it, i use FragmentTransactions to change the Fragment. To finish such a transaction, I have to call `commit()`. If I don't do this, Android Studio gives me this warning:

[image: Android Studio Code Inspection warning]

If you use a Toast and forget to call `show()` on it, there is a similar warning.

So my question is: Can I implement a custom inspection like this?

As Android Studio is based on the IntelliJ IDEA, this is probably a feature of IntelliJ.

Comment: See my question on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133113/writing-custom-lint-warning-to-check-for-custom-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a video on the [Android Developers Channel](https://youtu.be/eOV2owswDkE) it is the Structural Replace Feature of IntelliJ. The video moves forward quite fast so you can read [this article about the video content](https://medium.com/google-developers/about-10-things-you-probably-didn-t-know-you-could-do-in-android-studio-de231071b375#.vnhkpofz6).

In Android Studio/IntelliJ you can find the Structural Replace dialog via `Edit | Find | Replace Structurally`, create your pattern and click `Save Template`.

For more details, see also the [IntelliJ help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/structural-search-and-replace-general-procedure.html?origin=old_help) for this feature.